# Breaking up large data for RSA encryption

Tags: c, security, encryption, openssl

Recently we've been diving into using OpenSSL to help encrypt/decrypt some data we have. Each "client" will have Public/Private key pair and X509 Certificate given to them by a local Certificate Authority. I'm now looking into encrypting/decrypting data with that key pair.

Everything I've looked into show using the methods `RSA_public_encrypt` and `RSA_private_decrypt` for RSA encryption. But the amount of data I can encrypt at once is limited by `RSA_size(rsa) - 41` for the padding type RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING. So my question is how to encrypt larger amounts of data while sticking to our RSA scheme (no static keyphrases, etc). I was thinking about breaking the data up into chunks and then encrypting it but that seems like it's defeating the point of padding.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you break the data, you will find out, that the speed is prohibitively slow. The right method is

1. Generate random key for symmetric algorithm
2. encrypt the data using symmetric algorithm and the random key
3. encrypt the random key using your public key and store it in the encrypted form next (or before) the data.

Comment: Make sense. What's the best way to generate a random key in C? Use arc4random() to select random characters from UTF8? Is there a "Secure Random" class in openssl or c's stdlib?

Comment: @Staros arc4random() looks like a good choice as it sounds to imlement cryptographically strong RC4 generator. Yet I'd also take a look at erickson's answer in this question and check possibilities to use OpenPGP -- it would handle everything for you.

Comment: @Staros – Read the required number of bits from `/dev/random`. They don't need to be characters in any encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately OpenPGP and GnuPG are encumbered by a license that requires you to release all your source code if you use them.

Comment: @Oscar You must be talking about implementations. OpenPGP is a standard (RFC 2440 and RFC 4880, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880). The standard itself doesn't rule the license for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a standard like CMS (the basis of the S/MIME support in your email client) or PGP. There are libraries for both of these standards for just about every platform.

You will find that they are very similar in their approach to bulk data encryption, using a symmetric cipher to encrypt data and encrypting that secret key with the public key of the "message" recipients. This approach is secure and fast.

However, these standards go further, securely handling things you might not have thought about yet, like encrypting the data for multiple recipients, attaching meta-data to the encrypted content, etc. You also get interoperability with other software. For example, if you use S/MIME, you can use just about any email client on any platform to decrypt. In fact, depending on your integration requirements, you might not need to write any software yourself.

Using one of these well-established protocols won't solve all of your security problems, but it will make it more difficult to do something really dumb.

Comment: CMS isn't in the current version of OpenSSL on OS X. I think it gets introduced in 0.9.9 or 1.0. PKCS7 is though and I'm guessing that applies as well.

Comment: I was under the impression that CMS was a more advanced implementation of PKCS7. No idea how or why though.